# Trouble playing a flash movie using javascript in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer-8

I´m having a problem trying to play a flashMovie(swf file)...

Here is my code:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
    <param name="movie" value="nyauto_pageflip4.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="play" value="true"/>
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <embed 
        swLiveConnect="true"
        src="file.swf"
        quality="high"
        name="flash_flip"
        id="flash_flip"
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
        pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
    />
```

Then, I have a javascript function with the play line:

`$('flash_flip').Play();`

I have jQuery, but I already tryed with document.GetElementById =)

So, when this line executes, the flash movie plays.
This works in FF and Chrome, but not in ie8...

Is there any way to fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: this looks to be a common problem associated with IE8. out the posts I was able  to find so far others appear to be having the same problem.

Comment: http://amapplease.blogspot.com/2009/03/ie8-adobe-flash-player-fix.html for a workaround to get it to work, but if others visiting are viewing through ie8 it might not work